# Could a downwind cart, or “push-me, pull-me” boat of a substantially heavier size be propelled with the use of a CVT, or continuous gear?

Tags: gears, applied-mechanics, propulsion

As broadly proven now before the academia, a vehicle including a boat or cart (probably a glider too) can move faster than the speed of wind up to about 2.5-2.8 times with a propeller generating lift on one side of its blades which propels either wheels of the car or the screw of the boat.

(The public debate as broadly settled as of recently: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yCsgoLc_fzI&t=16s;

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackbird_(wind-powered_vehicle))

Would it be possible to use, say, a 10 times smaller propeller by area one with a propeller diameter than the latest human-sized one with a propeller of ca. 3.5 meters in diameter with a gear of 10:1 gear ration to achieve the same outcome as with the models above? If not, why not?

If yes, would it be possible to set it up with a continuous variable transmission allowing gear ratios to go from 100:1 (100 propeller revolutions to 1 wheel revolution) to 1:1 so as to bring a 10 times heavier body in motion as it continuously changing gear from 100:1 towards 1:1, and achieve substantially the same outcome as seen on the models? If not, why not?

This is for a school project, thank you for any help.

EDIT:

Wind speed would be +15 mph; the total payload plus vehicle weight would be 2 tons, propeller 70 centimeters with a CVT.

Comment: Does the propeller drive the wheels? Or do the wheels drive the propeller?

Comment: The funny thing with this design is that it is the propeller driving the wheels. As much as I understand it, it is basically the same as how sailboats can sail faster than the speed of downwind if they are not moving along with it, but say, they zig-zag. The wind passed a blade of the propeller/sail of boat, creating air with pressure higher than on the opposite side forcing the blade of the prop/sail, and the boat therewith, to move in that direction. The force so created is able to accelerate the vehicle to higher-than-wind speeds. And this is true with the propeller design even upwind.

Comment: The hope is to build a model that  would have a size more proportionate to the vehicle starting from a really low gear (100:1) so that a weak wind can bring into motion a heavy body with a small propeller. I think two orders of magnitude is ca. the difference that is probably needed relative to the models represented by Veritasiul (1:1 gear with ca. 10:1 propellers to wheel ration) if the propeller is going to be 10 the size of the wheel, the gear must be 10*10 greater. That’s the theory, that is.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721755/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start by looking at the true wind speed that you want to operate in, the speed ratio that you are trying to achieve, the course conditions, and the payload. The rest is all about optimization and what you can actually build. If you  are trying for best VMG upwind or downwind, you will need a big propeller. If you just want to try to go faster than the true wind speed in any direction, then that is a lot easier to do, and you don't need as big a propeller.

Driveline efficiency is a huge problem for these machines. You can't afford to loose 5% to a tranny. You need to be able to change gears to suit conditions and target speed ratio, but that usually means changing wheel size or changing a sheave. The actual range of gearing is pretty small - maybe 15% covers all possible operating conditions if you are capable of a speed ratio of 2.0

Comment: Thank you for the shedding light to this — a little disappointed. The wind speed is presumed at +15 mph, and instead of a 3.5 meters diameter propeller, the idea is to use one maybe 70 centimeters at gear ratio 100:1. The payload would be 2 metric tons instead of about 200 kg’s as in the Blackbird video. The question is whether it would be able to start moving, and if it did, the CVT would slowly move up. (I’ll edit the question.)

Comment: Is a CVT 100:1 not possible merely a 1.15:1?

Comment: I was just talking about what the machine needs top gear to bottom gear. The power from the turbine is directly related to the swept area. It probably won't move with less than a 2 meter turbine.  You probably need to go to a three bladed prop and 5 meter diameter or so to do much good. Turbines this size are a problem for experienced engineers. They have all kinds of vibration modes that tend to destroy them. You need a lot of controlled testing to not hurt people with it. They can take out a building when they fail. For a vehicle, they have to be balanced to a ridiculous level of accuracy.

Comment: Thank you, this is great input!